# How to make Gantt chart in latex using data from csv file?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfgantt

I am trying to make Gantt chart in latex from data in csv file. Can I import the file into latex and use tikx or pgfgantt to make the gantchart without manually entering the values?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you  provide a sample of the csv file you would like to import?

Comment: I don't have it yet. But I will provide it as soon as I have the file. The file will contain flight schedule information for number of aircraft. With departure and arrival locations and departure and arrival times. The gantt chart should have each aircraft on the x-axis and time on the y-axis.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is: yes you can.  It seems you are just asking about whether you can import and access the file values and not about how to go about making the gantt chart itself.  In this case, you can use the following from the `pgfplotstable` package:

```
\pgfplotstableread{data.csv}\data
```

A data point can be accessed like:

```
\pgfplotstablegetelem{row}{column}\of{\data}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotstableset{col sep=comma}
\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
column1,column2
1,5
2,6
3,7
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread{data.csv}\data
\pgfplotstablegetelem{2}{column2}\of{\data}
\pgfplotsretval

\end{document}
```

Note that `filecontents` is unnecessary, I just used it for this example so you could have a self-contained script.  Remove that, and using the `\pgfplotstableread{data.csv}\data` line you can load your external csv file.

[This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/192795/gantt-chart-how-to-make-month-and-day-like-in-ms-project-using-pgfgantt?rq=1) seems to answer the part about making the gantt chart itself.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The problem is how to make the gantt chart itself from the data imported. I will try to combine it  :)

Comment: Can you add a MWE containing a subset of the data of interest?  I could then modify my answer to include a basic gantt chart.