# using csvsimple inside a pgfgantt diagram?

Tags: csv, pgfgantt, csvsimple

Is there any possibility to use some data contained in a csv file to create milestone or bar inside a pgfgantt diagram ? And, if yes, how to do so ? Is this possible with csvsimple ? Is it possible to have one small example ?

thanks

Ok following the post [252308](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/252308/how-to-make-gantt-chart-in-latex-using-data-from-csv-file) (thank you cicada), this gives something like:

```
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotstableset{col sep=comma}
\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
column1,column2
1,5
2,4
3,7
\end{filecontents}
\definecolor{barblue}{RGB}{153,204,254}
\definecolor{groupblue}{RGB}{51,102,254}
\definecolor{linkred}{RGB}{165,0,33} 

\begin{document}


\pgfplotstableread{data.csv}\data
\pgfplotstablegetelem{1}{column2}\of{\data}
\begin{ganttchart}{1}{12}

\gantttitle{2011}{12} \\
\gantttitlelist{1,...,12}{1} \\
\ganttgroup{Group 1}{1}{7} \\
\ganttbar{Task 1}{1}{2} \\
\ganttlinkedbar{Task 2}{3}{7}
 \ganttnewline
 \ganttmilestone{Milestone}{7}
 \ganttnewline
\ganttbar{Final Task}{8}{12}
\ganttlink{elem2}{elem3}
\ganttlink{elem3}{elem4}\\

 \ganttmilestone{Milestone}{\pgfplotsretval}
 
\end{ganttchart}

\end{document}
```

That's ok for one single point ...
But how to automatically add all the data ?

Let's say that the csv file correponds to something like this:

```
\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
task, date
task1,01-08-2022
task2,05-08-2022
task3,20-08-2022
\end{filecontents}
```

How to automatically load all the data to obtain something equivalent to this:

```
\ganttmilestone{task1}{01-08-2022}
\ganttmilestone{task2}{05-08-2022}
\ganttmilestone{task3}{20-08-2022}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.se.

Comment: have you seen https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/252308/how-to-make-gantt-chart-in-latex-using-data-from-csv-file and the linked question?

Comment: Are you looking for a ready-made package solution, or are you having a problem or issue or error with a particular step or code? What have you tried so far? Copying code at random is not helpful and is misleading (to me) of what your requirements are.

Answer (score 1):

Example of milestone file data added to a pgfgantt chart using IO and mapping functions of expl3.

The Gantt chart and the file data must line up to the same time period for meaningful display (2011 chart with 2022 data is not practical at a month, week or day level).

[image: milestones]

MWE

```
\begin{filecontents*}{mdata.csv}
task, date

task1,01-08-2022
task2,05-08-2022
task3,20-08-2022
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{barblue}{RGB}{153,204,254}
\definecolor{groupblue}{RGB}{51,102,254}
\definecolor{linkred}{RGB}{165,0,33} 


\ExplSyntaxOn


\tl_new:N \g_gc_milestonename_tl
\tl_new:N \g_gc_milestonedate_tl
\seq_new:N \g_gc_milestonelist_seq



%++++++++++++++++++++++++++


        \cs_generate_variant:Nn 
            \seq_gset_split:Nnn 
            { Nno }
        \cs_generate_variant:Nn 
            \seq_set_split:Nnn 
            { Nno }


%****************************************************
%*
%****************************************************
%------------------
    \cs_set:Npn \ic_funcmilestone:n #1 { 
    % 1=data line :: task1,01-08-2022

    \seq_set_split:Nno 
            \l_tmpa_seq  
            { , } 
            { #1 }
            
    %milestone name
    \tl_gset:Nx 
            \g_gc_milestonename_tl
            {
                \seq_item:Nn
                        \l_tmpa_seq
                        { 1 }
            }

    %milestone date
    \tl_gset:Nx 
            \g_gc_milestonedate_tl
            {
                \seq_item:Nn
                        \l_tmpa_seq
                        { 2 }
            }

        %add to chart
         \ganttmilestone
                    { \g_gc_milestonename_tl }
                    { \g_gc_milestonedate_tl }
             \ganttnewline

}




%****************************************************
%*
%****************************************************
%------------------
    \cs_set:Npn \ic_funcgline:n #1 { 
    % 1=line from file
    
    %add it to the list
    \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl { #1 }
    \seq_gput_right:NV
            \g_gc_milestonelist_seq
             \l_tmpa_tl 

    }
    
    
%io stream name 
\ior_new:N \g_gc_getfile_ior


\NewDocumentCommand { \getfilemilestones } { m }
 {% #1 = file name
        
    \seq_gclear:N \g_gc_milestonelist_seq
  
  %read the milestone data      
  \ior_open:Nn \g_gc_getfile_ior { #1 }
        \ior_map_inline:Nn
                \g_gc_getfile_ior
                { 
                        \ic_funcgline:n { ##1 }
                }
  \ior_close:N \g_gc_getfile_ior
                
%  \seq_show:N \g_gc_milestonelist_seq              

        %remove header
        \seq_gset_eq:NN
                \g_tmpa_seq
                \g_gc_milestonelist_seq
        \seq_pop_left:NN
                \g_tmpa_seq
                \l_tmpb_tl
        %add milestones to chart
        \seq_map_function:NN
                \g_tmpa_seq
                \ic_funcmilestone:n

}



\ExplSyntaxOff



\begin{document}


\begin{ganttchart}[
x unit=4mm,
time slot format=little-endian,
]{01-08-2022}{31-08-2022}
\gantttitlecalendar{year, month, day} \\
\getfilemilestones{mdata.csv}
\ganttnewline
\end{ganttchart}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried to test your solution (by running `pdflatex testgantcsv2.tex` in command line) but obtained the following error message: 
`\openout15 = mdata.csv.
! Package pgfgantt Error: Illegal time slot specifier  l.137 \getfilemilestones{mdata.csv}`
I also tried to remove the command `\getfilemilestones{mdata.csv} ` just to check if the message `Error: Illegal time slot specifier ` was relevant or not. 
It was not ! Compilation in this case succeeded. 
I saw what you obtained ... therefore what could cause such error ?

Comment: I compile OK with lualatex and pdflatex using TexLive 2022 on Windows with no errors. Line 137 in my code is blank. Ask a separate question, with the code you *actually* ran, and what your setup is (system, package versions, log messages, etc). I presume all time slots must be consistent - if they are specified as little-endian and one is formatted as big-endian, I would expect an error to generate, so that could be a place to start looking.

Comment: Thank, It's done :  [661772](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/661772/error-message-pgfgantt-missing-number-treated-as-zero-using-csvsimple-ins)